# OSX: shaking the mouse during compiler output makes it go faster. Why?

Tags: compilation-mode

I frequently run a Maven job in compilation mode. Maven is very verbose and spews all sorts of stuff to the screen. The build as you might imagine runs for a while.

Randomly, while bored and waiting for this job to complete, I happened to notice that if I shake the mouse over the (focused) window the speed with which the output is written increases significantly.  What could be the reason for this? (I'm prepared for something awful.)

Emacs 28.1 aarch64-apple-darwin21.1.0; OSX 13.5.1

Comment: I'll hazard a *total guess* that maybe it's to do with testing for pending user inputs and finding something immediately rather than waiting a moment to see if anything turns up?